# How to create a link to a page in a WordPress theme

Tags: php

I am building a WordPress theme with two pages (home & contact) but when I click on the contact, it doesn't show me the page... Maybe there is a problem in my path defining how can I give it a right path

```
<li>
    <a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
</li>
```

```html
<nav class="topnavbar navbar-default topnav">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed toggle-costume" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#upmenu" aria-expanded="false">
     <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigaion</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/image/logo1.png" alt="logo"></a>
   </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="upmenu">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbarontop">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a> </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CATEGORIES <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdowncostume">
      <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Old</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">DEALERS <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdowncostume">
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
 
    </li>
    <button><span class="postnewcar">POST NEW CAR</span></button>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey hadi butt, welcome to SO! Have you tried adding a `/` in front of the file name? Try changing it to `/contact.php`

Comment: Remove the .php and to go one better add <?php get_site_url(); ?>/contact so whether you are on dev, staging, or production the link will always work.